# Can "direction" have sides?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

I am trying to describe the positional relationship among objects A, B, and C with reference to direction X. The relationship may be described as follows when it is literally translated from my language to English:

> 1. Object A is located on (located closest to) one side of direction X.
> 2. Object B is located between objects A and C in direction X.
> 3. Object C is located on (located closest to) the other side of direction X.

I think the second is acceptable, but the first and third do not make sense. I would like to know how to describe the positional relationship with reference to direction?
[image]

Comment: Is this with reference to an abstract direction and objects (e.g. as in a mathematics paper) or an actual direction and objects (e.g. when giving directions)?

Comment: It is an abstract direction that the writer defined.

Comment: You've labeled it "direction X" but you seem to be labeling an axis, not a direction.  "one" and "the other" look like labels for directions, but they look like directions that lie *along* X, *not* that are on either side of X.  If anything, they're likely on either side of Y.

Comment: A *direction* is more like a ray than a line. If drawn, it should only have an arrow at one end, not both ends.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the literal translations. What are some words that could fill in for X? "East" and "west", "right" and "left", "toward the door" and "away from the door", "along the _x_ axis", something else?

Comment: You probably need vector in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direction is used here in ways that don't work within English.  I think you have translated into the wrong word.

**Path** is an English word that describes some way of moving between items.  A path can have sides, but when we say "on one side of the path" we mean on the area that is not part of the path.  To fix your description, we would say "at one end of the path".

- Object A is located on one end of the path X.
- Object B is located between objects A and C on the path X.
- Object C is located on the other end of the path X.

Note that this describes a path with ends, if the path continues beyond A and C, then we probably would say

- Along the path, we find A, B, and C in that order.

Paths are the most general way of describing a way to move between items.  They do not need to be straight, they just connect items.  If the path is straight, we would use the word **line**, to show the path is straight.  **line segment** is formally used to indicate the parts of lines that have endings and beginnings, but informally **line** can be used too.

- Object A is located on one end of the line X.
- Object B is located between objects A and C on the line X.
- Object C is located on the other end of the line X.

If the parts of the path are line segments, but the overall path is not linear, we use the word **angle** focusing on the point at which the two paths meet.

- There is an angle between A, B, and C.
- A, B, and C form an angle, with B between A and C.

Or in formal math notebooks

- The angle ABC

Comment: Welcome to ELL! It's great to see such thoughtful answers, so carefully explained.

Answer (score 0):

The direction is irrelevant when describing the relative locations. The positional relationship can be described as

> The three objects A, B and C lie on a straight line. B is between A
>   and C.

or

> The three objects A, B and C are colinear. B is between A and C.

If you really want to include the direction: suppose direction X is turned 90 degrees. Then

> The three objects A, B and C are all the same distance in direction X.

Comment: Assuming that direction X is the vertical direction, we can say object A is located above objects B and C, Object B is located between Objects A and C in the vertical direction.  I would like to know how to describe the positional relationship when  the vertical direction is generalized to direction X.

Comment: @ rama9              There's no way—a direction is a straight line, right? Either you've got to relate objects to this line (closer, farther) or you've got to set a point of reference on the line (any of the objects might be such a point). So, when you say that A is the farthest in the directon X and B is located between A and C, you actually count C as a reference point.

Answer (score 0):

Some directions have clear names. So we can say A is "above", "below", "East" or "West" of B

Or we can use relative directions "to the right of B"

If we want to talk about the direction of "A" relative to the direction of "C" we could say "C is on one side of B, and A is on the other side of B"

This only makes sense if you mention three objects. You can't just say "A is located on the other side of direction X" without also mentioning object C

We don't add "of direction X" or any similar phrase. We can also just say "B is between A and C"

Answer (score 0):

> the object A is on the left of the object B, while C on the right of that.
>   The object B is between the objects A and C. A is on the side of B, while C on the opposite direction of that.
>   the object C is on the other side of direction X, while A is the one side of that direction, and B is in the middle of them.